# Haskell How should I check and return the elements in one tuple that partially exists in the other tuple?

Tags: list, haskell

I am new to Haskell programming, I currently Have a list1 [[String]] that contains

> [["H1","B1"],["H2","B2"],["H3","B2"]]

and another List2 [[String]]

> [["H1","B1","H5"],["H2","B2","H5"],["H2","H3","B2"],["H5","B1","H4"]]

and I want to return a result based on list2 that contains elements in List1 like

> [["H1","B1","H5"],["H2","B2","H5"],["H2","H3","B2"]]

does anyone understand what I mean? 
I totally have no idea how to start on this problem, Thanks for helping
I want to use it as filter and what I design was

```
isInList :: [[String]] -> [[String]] -> Bool
isInList (x:xs) y = filter (any (`elem` x)) y
```

But this gave me a wrong answer [["H1","B1","H5"],["H5","B1","H4"]]
where did I wrong?

Comment: what did you tried already?

Comment: Why should the last list not be part of the output? What do you mean with tuple, these are lists.

Comment: Because the last list doesn't contain any any pairs in List 1,

Comment: Please first show what you've tried. Right now this looks like a "solve my homework for me"-question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example output contains the first three sublists from `List2`. Your `List1` is of length 3. Do you want to truncate `List2` to the length of `List1`? If so, try

```
list1 = [["H1","B1"],["H2","B2"],["H3","B2"]]
list2 = [["H1","B1","H5"],["H2","B2","H5"],["H2","H3","B2"]]

truncatedList2 = take (length list1) list2

main = print truncatedList2
```

Try [running the Haskell snippet](http://codepad.org/fOgOCQ4a).